# Timeline plugin issue in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I tried to use the timeline plugin and post to my timeline using this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/). and everything worked as a charm. The problem occurred when I tried to implement the same to my WordPress [blog](http://blog.mist.sk). The timeline plugin doesn't refresh after I authorized the app to add actions to my timeline and sometimes after the refresh, I see the Facebook logo (error page) instead of the plugin. Updating the timeline also doesn't work because of "an active access token must be used to query information about the current user" error.

I tried to use the very same app, so I assume that there is something wrong going on with WordPress. Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. A plugin had a reference to the old all.js